# What is, "unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'float'"

Tags: python

I don't know why my code isn't working. 
this is my code:

```
# Chapter 1 Problem 2

distance = input("Enter a distance in kilometers:  ")

print ("You entered ")
print (distance, "km") 
print ("Which is equivalent to ")
print (distance / 1.61)
```

The error is:

> "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'float'"

I know that it's because of the division, but I cannot figure out how to divide the my input with 1.61.

Comment: `input` returns a `str`ing, convert it to a float using `float(input("..."))`.

Comment: so it would be, "print float(input( / 1.61))"?

Comment: because float keeps giving me an error

Comment: Convert `distance` to a float as soon as it's entered: `distance = float(input("Enter a distance in kilometers:  "))`

Comment: okay, sorry to keep bothering you, but now it's saying I can't  divide the user input with 1.61.

Comment: Please show us the actual error message.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ogechianyanwu/Documents/2019-2020/CSC 106/Chapter 1 Problem 2 .py", line 10, in <module>
    print (input/1.61)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'builtin_function_or_method' and 'float'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I read inputs as numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449427/how-can-i-read-inputs-as-numbers)

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```py
distance = float(input("Enter a distance in kilometers:  "))

print ("You entered ")
print (distance, "km") 
print ("Which is equivalent to ")
print (distance / 1.61)
```

`input` returns string value, since you are doing a `float` division, both the operands must be of `float`. So, we convert the input value to `float`.

Comment: Happy to know that. You can see the difference in the first line of the code.

Comment: @OgechiAnyanwu What's unclear from the code? You take the return value of `input`, and you pass it to the `float` function. You might want to review sections about taking numerical input in your Python instructional materials.

Comment: @OgechiAnyanwu, you can accept this as answer if you are happy with it.